# google maps not displayed

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting a problem in implementing a simple HelloGoogleMaps tutorial given at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html
The problem is that everything seems fine, but on running the code, only the grid and google logo appears, also if I add another layer of markers, the markers show up but not the underlying map.
There is internet connection in the emulator as on all the other applications network is connected.
Somebody please help me.
The display on the console is :

```
[2011-10-19 18:17:21 - helloGoogleMaps] ------------------------------
[2011-10-19 18:17:21 - helloGoogleMaps] Android Launch!
[2011-10-19 18:17:21 - helloGoogleMaps] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-19 18:17:21 - helloGoogleMaps] Performing c.om.maps.my.HelloGoogleMapsActivity activity launch
[2011-10-19 18:17:21 - helloGoogleMaps] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'maps'
[2011-10-19 18:17:21 - helloGoogleMaps] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'maps'
[2011-10-19 18:17:29 - helloGoogleMaps] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-10-19 18:17:29 - helloGoogleMaps] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-10-19 18:18:51 - helloGoogleMaps] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-19 18:18:51 - helloGoogleMaps] Uploading helloGoogleMaps.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-19 18:18:51 - helloGoogleMaps] Installing helloGoogleMaps.apk...
[2011-10-19 18:19:35 - helloGoogleMaps] Success!
[2011-10-19 18:19:35 - helloGoogleMaps] Starting activity c.om.maps.my.HelloGoogleMapsActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-10-19 18:19:38 - helloGoogleMaps] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=c.om.maps.my/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity }
[2011-10-19 18:41:48 - helloGoogleMaps] ------------------------------
```

The last portion of Log cat ouyputs ::

```
10-19 19:56:52.357: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps for broadcast com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.NlpPackageUpdateReceiver: pid=346 uid=10018 gids={3003, 1015}
10-19 19:56:52.787: DEBUG/dalvikvm(182): GC_EXPLICIT freed 292K, 49% free 2956K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 672ms
10-19 19:56:53.147: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(70): no available voice recognition services found
10-19 19:56:54.248: DEBUG/dalvikvm(70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 784K, 45% free 4854K/8711K, external 4373K/5461K, paused 290ms
10-19 19:56:54.347: INFO/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.google.android.maps.LocalSuggestionProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.LocalSuggestionProvider
10-19 19:56:54.357: INFO/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.google.android.maps.LayerInfoProvider: com.google.googlenav.layer.LayerInfoProvider
10-19 19:56:54.377: INFO/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@c.om.maps.my-1.apk@classes.dex
10-19 19:56:54.438: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(202): Shutting down VM
10-19 19:56:54.457: DEBUG/dalvikvm(202): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 294K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+1ms
10-19 19:56:54.479: DEBUG/jdwp(202): adbd disconnected
10-19 19:56:54.497: INFO/AndroidRuntime(202): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-19 19:56:54.587: INFO/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.google.android.maps.TrafficProvider: com.google.googlenav.appwidget.traffic.TrafficProvider
10-19 19:56:54.587: INFO/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.google.android.maps.SuggestionProvider: com.google.googlenav.suggest.android.SuggestProvider
10-19 19:56:54.637: INFO/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.google.android.maps.SearchHistoryProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.SearchHistoryProvider
10-19 19:56:54.657: INFO/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.google.android.maps.NavigationAvailabilityProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.NavigationAvailabilityProvider
10-19 19:56:55.327: INFO/ActivityThread(346): Pub com.google.android.maps.StarredItemProvider: com.google.googlenav.provider.StarredItemProvider
10-19 19:56:55.739: DEBUG/dalvikvm(346): GC_CONCURRENT freed 835K, 49% free 3476K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 8ms+8ms
10-19 19:56:56.337: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=362 uid=10010 gids={}
10-19 19:56:56.527: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(360): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-19 19:56:56.527: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(360): CheckJNI is ON
10-19 19:56:57.397: INFO/ActivityThread(362): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
10-19 19:56:57.548: DEBUG/GTalkService(204): handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
10-19 19:56:57.557: DEBUG/GTalkService(204): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
10-19 19:56:57.587: DEBUG/GTalkService(204): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
10-19 19:56:58.417: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(360): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
10-19 19:56:58.569: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=c.om.maps.my/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity } from pid 360
10-19 19:56:58.807: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(360): Shutting down VM
10-19 19:56:58.856: DEBUG/dalvikvm(360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 69% free 318K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+32ms
10-19 19:56:58.856: INFO/AndroidRuntime(360): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-19 19:56:58.866: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Start proc c.om.maps.my for activity c.om.maps.my/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity: pid=378 uid=10038 gids={3003, 1015}
10-19 19:56:58.877: DEBUG/jdwp(360): adbd disconnected
10-19 19:56:59.367: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 50% free 2719K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 475ms
10-19 19:56:59.707: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 50% free 2719K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 306ms
10-19 19:56:59.966: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 50% free 2719K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 246ms
10-19 19:57:00.237: WARN/ActivityManager(70): finishReceiver called but no pending broadcasts
10-19 19:57:01.737: DEBUG/dalvikvm(378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1168K, 54% free 3144K/6727K, external 1626K/2137K, paused 7ms+7ms
10-19 19:57:02.187: DEBUG/dalvikvm(378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 529K, 51% free 3304K/6727K, external 1626K/2137K, paused 9ms+9ms
10-19 19:57:02.838: INFO/MapActivity(378): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
10-19 19:57:02.847: ERROR/MapActivity(378): Couldn't get connection factory client
10-19 19:57:03.177: DEBUG/dalvikvm(378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 810K, 54% free 3121K/6727K, external 2046K/2137K, paused 6ms+11ms
10-19 19:57:03.217: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed c.om.maps.my/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity: +4s421ms
10-19 19:57:04.397: VERBOSE/MediaProvider(257): Attached volume: external
10-19 19:57:04.797: VERBOSE/MediaScanner(257): pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@405c3dd8
10-19 19:57:04.797: VERBOSE/MediaScanner(257): /pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@405c3dd8
10-19 19:57:04.817: DEBUG/MediaScanner(257):  prescan time: 321ms
10-19 19:57:04.817: DEBUG/MediaScanner(257):     scan time: 14ms
10-19 19:57:04.817: DEBUG/MediaScanner(257): postscan time: 57ms
10-19 19:57:04.827: DEBUG/MediaScanner(257):    total time: 392ms
10-19 19:57:04.838: DEBUG/MediaScannerService(257): done scanning volume external
10-19 19:57:14.308: INFO/InputReader(70): Device reconfigured: id=0x0, name=qwerty2, display size is now 480x800
10-19 19:57:14.308: INFO/InputManager-Callbacks(70): No virtual keys found for device qwerty2.
10-19 19:57:15.248: INFO/ARMAssembler(70): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00001004_00000000 [ 65 ipp] (85 ins) at [0x445fd520:0x445fd674] in 1499783 ns
10-19 19:57:15.377: INFO/ARMAssembler(70): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x445fd678:0x445fd840] in 813025 ns
10-19 19:57:25.087: DEBUG/dalvikvm(378): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 89K, 54% free 3145K/6727K, external 2046K/2137K, paused 138ms
10-19 19:57:43.808: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(378): No keyboard for id 0
10-19 19:57:43.887: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(378): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Comment: The console doesn't really say much, try posting the logcat output instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate MapView API key from your debug.keystore file.
read here how to do this http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: This is definitely your problem, you must have a valid maps api key before Google will send actual map data to your application.

Comment: I have done the whole process.... extracting MD5 fingerprint from my debug.keystore file, then giving this fingerprint to get the android maps api key. still no affect

Comment: Thy to setup permission to the internet for your app. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: permissions already given in manifest of the project. Stil no maps

Comment: Try to run project from this post (you can find link to source). http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/how-to-implement-lazy-loading-for-markers-on-google-maps-in-android .Before running please setup your API key in layout

Comment: I think there is no internet connection in my simulation .... even google.com doesnt show up in the browser

Comment: This is good idea. Did you try go to internet from your emulator through default browser?

Comment: To meke internet connection please do next: Run cmd.exe. Write "emulator.exe -avd <AVD name> -dns-server 8.8.8.8 [-scale <scale>]", where:
2.1. <AVD name> - your Android Virtual Device name;
2.2. [-scale <scale>] - optional parameter - scale the emulator window. <scale> is a number between 0.1 and 3 that represents the desired scaling factor. You can also specify scale as a DPI value if you add the suffix "dpi" to the scale value. A value of "auto" tells the emulator to select the best window size.
2.3. -dns-server 8.8.8.8 - Google Public DNS address. More information you can find here.

Comment: sorry couldnt get you @ihrupin

Comment: in your code also the same problem occuring... may be there is a problem of proxy settings that my connection has to pass through.